# EXCEL XML Format is not really standard?

Tags: c#, xml, excel

From:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excelxmlreport.aspx

```
<Cell>
  <Data ss:Type="Number">25</Data>
</Cell>
```

As far as I'm concerned, that's valid XML. However Excel 2003 complains when it opens up that XML document with a message in a dialog box, "Problems During Load".

Why does Microsoft doesn't really conform to XML ?

Update: I don't understand how http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FE118952-3547-420A-A412-00A2662442D9&displaylang=en can require one single line xml style ?

Comment: It can be a valid XML, and still remain invalid for Excel.

Comment: Why do you think that every xml document should be a valid excel document? If a document format is based on xml that just means that every valid document is valid xml, not the other way round.

Answer (score 3):

Excel supports XML-based files, but the file must conform to some rules (excel XML sheet XSD schema).

Look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats#Excel_XML_Spreadsheet_example) example:

Try export a sample excel sheet to an XML file to preview the structure.

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FE118952-3547-420A-A412-00A2662442D9&displaylang=en) is  Office 2003 XML Reference Schemas Set.

Comment: You beat me to my answer :P +1 if you fix the link

Comment: Refer to http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/using-xml-in-excel-HA001189530.aspx?CTT=1 aswell.

Comment: I don't understand your answer how can xml spec can require one single line xml style ?